Emission shade problem
Does anyone know why the color of the emission or bloom is giving me a different color than the one of the material?


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

The color of the material is dead white, correct? Like the hexadecimal code is FFFFFF and not FEFFFF etc?
